# Geometry and related to Circles

Tags: geometry, circles

Two concentric circles are given, with two points initial at some point parallel to each other, v1 is given which is angle of movement of the point in circle A, v2 is given which is angle of movement of the point in circle B, at time t.

Movements are per unit time until t, after the points are moved then what is the distance between two points, where radii of circles are given?

Comment: What did you try?